# How to send data in facebook Game Request in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am making a Game app wherein I want to send invite to user to accept my Game Challenge. So what I want to do is I want to send Challenge_Id to user through *facebook*.

**What I have already done:**

I have used `GameRequestDialog` from which users can be selected to send APP Request. In `GameRequestDialog` I have passed the id of custom object as well. See code below:

```
   GameRequestDialog requestDialog = new GameRequestDialog(getActivity());
   requestDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<GameRequestDialog.Result>() {
        public void onSuccess(GameRequestDialog.Result result) {
        }

        public void onCancel() {
        }

        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        }
    });

GameRequestContent content = new GameRequestContent.Builder()
                .setMessage("Accept challenge.")
                .setTitle("SendChallenge")
                .setActionType(GameRequestContent.ActionType.SEND)
                .setObjectId("******************") // Deliberately Hidden
                .build();
    requestDialog.show(content);
```

Now I don't know how to pass dynamic Challenge Id to custom object ?

Open graph API's method are also welcomed...

Comment: Where are you getting your object ID from?